# Can't open a PDF downloaded using res.send(data)-express

Tags: node.js, express, pdf, static, serving

I am having trouble whit this simple piece of code:

```
fs.readFile('public/PDF/Booklet_nl.pdf', (err,data)=>{
if(err){
throw err
 
}

res.send(data);
 });
```

The file can be downloaded but I am not able to visualize the PDF in the browser.

Comment: I just fixed it using res.setHeader('content-type' , 'application/PDF')

Comment: but still does not work on mobiles.

Answer (score 0):

For that, You should set headers as following:

```
res.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/pdf');
res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=application.pdf');
 res.send(data);
```